# NestJS run guard(like) process before initializing dynamic REQUEST scoped providers

Tags: authentication, nestjs, passport.js, lifecycle

In NestJS I have a REQUEST scoped provider that is using a useFactory: async (req) => arrow function and I planned to have a guard add the user to the request so the provider could use it to configure the dynamic provider, this however doesn't work. in the entire ⁠[lifecycle of nestjs](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle#summary) there seems to be no place that I have tried that can successfully precede the provider initialization, no global guard, or no global middleware. Is there a way to modify the request before the REQUEST scoped provider is initialized?
(I'm using a passport strategy in the guard. Currently there is duplicate authentication inside the provider... yuck).

Comment: What's the need for reading properties of the request inside the initialization? Could you "kick the can down the road" so to say, and use a getter of the request _later_ to allow the guard to run before hand and still let whatever dynamic logic you have take action, just at a later point in the cycle?